# How can I create a single dynamic user page to process any user from their unique id

Tags: php

I have a form that submits to the database. From there I would like to generate a unique url and populate that page with data from the database.

How could I go about this using only one page. I need the url ending `http://sample.com/UNIQUEID` to be unique so that every user has their own link. However, I don't know how to do it without creating 100's of pages in my file manager.

### HTML

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name">
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email">
</form>
```

### PHP

```
<?php
    require_once('config.php');

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

        if (!empty($_POST['name'])) {
            $name = filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        };
        if (!empty($_POST['email'])) {
            $email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
        };
    };

    try {
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname;charset=$charset', '$username', '$password');
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

        $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO user (name, email) VALUES (:name, :email)');

        $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
        $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    };
?>
```

Comment: Sidenote: variables only populate inside double quotes or concatenated. This will fail `'mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname;charset=$charset' , '$username', '$password'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an `.htaccess` issue.

Add this code to your `.htaccess` file:

```
# Turns on Mod-Rewrite Engine
# ----------------------------------------------------------------
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

# Pages 
# ----------------------------------------------------------------
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ WHATEVER-PAGE.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

On the `WHATEVER-PAGE.php` you get the `id` through:

`$user = $_REQUEST['id'];` and do your normal processing from there.

Recommended .htaccess review if beginner:

https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: I updated the code... had the rewrite rule commented... removed the comment (#)

Comment: I don't htaccess is good for his situation he should use a framework for easier usage :)

Comment: If you are referring to some type of template system like smarty I disagree. If you are referring to a framework like Foundation 5 I would agree life would be easier, however, I believe that .htaccess and knowledge thereof is a vital aspect of modern web design.